# Subquery in pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, report, pivot

I am using dynamic pivot query to generate a report:

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns2 VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @Columns = ''
SET @Columns2 = ''

SELECT 
    @Columns = @Columns + (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') 
FROM 
    efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
WHERE 
    1=1 
    AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -5 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
    AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)

SET @Columns = LEFT(@Columns, LEN(@Columns) - 1)

SELECT  
    @Columns2 = @Columns2 + 'ISNULL(' +(QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',0)AS'+(QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') )
FROM 
    efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
WHERE 
    1=1 
    AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -5 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
    AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)

SET @Columns2 = LEFT(@Columns2, LEN(@Columns2) - 1)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @SQL = ''

SET @SQL = 'WITH BaseData AS
                (
                     select 
                        vendor_code,
                        RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [CLOSED_DATE]) as char(15))))+'','' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([CLOSED_DATE]) as char(20)))) as [CLOSED_DATE],
                        count(vendor_code) as [No. of Case] 
                   from #teamp t WITH (NOLOCK)
                      where 
                       [CLOSED_DATE] is not null
                  group by 
                       vendor_code, CLOSED_DATE
                )   
                SELECT  vendor_code,' + @Columns2 + 'FROM BaseData
                PIVOT
                (
                    sum([No. of Case])
                    FOR CLOSED_DATE IN (' +  @Columns + ')
                ) AS PivotTable'

--Print @SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Now I want to add vendor name with the Vendor code in my report.Vendor name come for different table

```
 SELECT VendorName 
 FROM VENDOR_REQUIREMENT  
 WHERE vendorcode = 'ACEA'
```

Please advice me where I have to use my select to get vendorname !

Please find the sample data
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join to the vendor_requirement table in your BaseData cte and select the vendorname where it's needed.  you also need to group by the new field where you do your count()

```
SET @SQL = 'WITH BaseData AS
                (
                   select 
                        t.vendor_code,
                        vr.vendorname,
                        RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [CLOSED_DATE]) as char(15))))+'','' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([CLOSED_DATE]) as char(20)))) as [CLOSED_DATE],
                        count(t.vendor_code) as [No. of Case] 
                   from #teamp t WITH (NOLOCK)
                   join (select distinct vendorcode, vendorname from  vendor_requirement) vr on t.vendor_code = vr.vendorcode
                   where 
                       [CLOSED_DATE] is not null
                   group by 
                       t.vendor_code, vr.vendorname, CLOSED_DATE
                )   
                SELECT  vendor_code,vendorname,' + @Columns2 + 'FROM BaseData
                PIVOT
                (
                    sum([No. of Case])
                    FOR CLOSED_DATE IN (' + @Columns + ')
                ) AS PivotTable'
                --Print @SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: its giving me the vendor name but wrong number of cases. because of join

Comment: do you have another table that has one vendor name per vendor code besides vendor_requirement ?  is vendor code unique per vendor?

Comment: vendor code is unique per vendor . but both the table have the lots of different data for particular vendor

Comment: Please find the sample data

Comment: ah just select distinct then if that's what you have to use.. see update

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from where #teamp table is coming. Joining to that table should do.

from #teamp t WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN VENDOR_REQUIREMENT V ON T.vendor_code=V.vendor_code

Comment: after inner joint it giving me wrong "sum([No. of Case])"